# No sound unless I have the sound settings window open

Tags: audio, headset, polycom

App: Itunes
Platform: Win 10
Headset: Plantronics 8200 UC w/BT600 dongle

While playing audio, I have no sound unless I open the sound setting.  If I close this window the app continues to play, but there is not sound.  this does not occur when I select desktop speakers.

Comment: I have exactly this problem too, with a Poly BT700 USB Bluetooth audio adaptor.